# Azure Search Complex types faceting by filtered nested properties is based on found objects

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search complex types preview API (2017-11-11-Preview) for filtering/faceting by complex types. All of my filters and facets are creating on properties in nested type (not root type) and looks like they are not combining on the right nesting level but only through document root.
For example, I have the next document in the search index

```
{ 
  apartmentComplexId: "1",
  apartmentTypes: [
    { 
      bedroomCount: 1,
      bathroomCount: 2
    },
    { 
      bedroomCount: 2,
      bathroomCount: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

`apartmentTypes.bedroomCount` and `apartmentTypes.bathroomCount` are faceted and filtered. Facet result for dataset will return

```
{
  "apartmentTypes/bedroomCount": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  "apartmentTypes/bathroomCount": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

When I'm executing the next query:

```
$filter=apartmentTypes/any(x: x/bedroomCount eq 1)&facet=apartmentTypes/bathroomCount
```

my facets collection in response contains all two possible facet values for bathroomCount - 2 and 3 with value of 1 for each of them.

```
{
  "apartmentTypes/bathroomCount": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

By the next step I'm trying to use facet data in my more concrete filter

```
$filter=apartmentTypes/any(x: x/bedroomCount eq 1 and x/bathroomCount eq 3)
```

Oops, I've got empty resultset.

I understand that more correct filter string should be something like

```
$filter=apartmentTypes/any(x: x/bedroomCount) and values/any(x: x/bathroomcount eq 3)
```

but I need the functionality exactly like this - found entity should contain the item in its collection with all the faceted results.

Comment: Faceting and filtering both operate at document-scope, not at the scope of items in a complex collection (although you can write correlated filters on a complex collection, as in your first example). This is by design. Can you explain in a little more detail why the second filter won't work for your scenario?

Comment: I've added facet results for each step for more detailed explanation

Comment: That doesn't really explain *why* you "need the functionality exactly like this". It might help if you describe it in terms of the end-user experience you're trying to create. At this point, I don't understand why you wouldn't just emit the correct non-correlated filter.

Comment: I have a list of apartment complexes with apartment types. And I want to filter this list by apartment type properties - the number of bedrooms, bathrooms and so on. So when the user searches complexes with 2 bedroom and 1 bathroom apartment - I can't show him complexes, which contains 2 bedroom or 1 bathroom apartment.

Comment: Thanks. I've renamed the fields in your examples to ground them in the actual problem domain. It makes it easier to reason about.

Now I understand why you want to execute the filter that puts the "and" condition inside the "any" -- that makes perfect sense. But per your question, if you filter for apartment complexes that contain 1 bedroom and 3 bathrooms, you *should* get no results, because no such apartment type exists. Is the issue with how the facets are presented?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's the case when faceted navigation is failing for me.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks for your patience. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faceting and filtering both operate at document-scope, not at the scope of items in a complex collection (although you can write correlated filters on a complex collection, as in your first example). This is by design.

In your scenario, this is leading to a mismatch of user expectations with the system's behavior. As a user, if I'm clicking through facets describing apartments, I'm naturally going to assume that filtering is happening on apartments too, but it's actually happening on apartment *complexes*. This is why the empty resultset in your example is so unintuitive.

I would recommend modeling your indexes according to how users will navigate. Assuming users typically search for apartments, not apartment complexes, try making `apartmentType` the document type and denormalize the apartment complex information if necessary.

In the meantime, please consider creating an item on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) to help us prioritize adding support for correlated facets over complex collections.